# how do I return value only in finaly block override firebase login

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

```
 tryToLogin(email:string,password:string) {
  var success:boolean
  this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
  .then((firebaseUser)=>{
    // on success
    success = true
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    //on fail
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
    success = false
  }).finally(()=>{
    return success
  })
}
```

this one doesn't work.
it returns undefined.

any ideas (maybe somehow with async, await and promises)

Comment: You can remove `finally` and put `return success` at the end of method (outside auth block)

Comment: Yet I get undefined because it returns it before the login  success/fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure if this is what you want. But you could convert promise to an observable using RxJS `map` and apply operators such as `map` and `catchError` to return the `success` variable that you require.

```js
import { from, of } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

tryToLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  return from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)).pipe(
    map(firebaseUser => {
      // on success
      return true;
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      // on error
      return of(false);      // <-- you need to return an observable from `catchError` - so use `of`
    })
  );
}
```

Now since you're returning an observable instead of a Promise, you could subscribe to the function where it's used.

```js
this.someService.tryToLogin(...).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),   // <-- will print `true` on successful login and `false` on failed login
  error => { }
);
```

---

If you however wish to get a `error` notification instead of a `next` notification, you need to throw the error from the `catchError` block. You could use RxJS `throwError` function.

```js
import { throwError, from } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catchError } from 'rxjs/operators';

tryToLogin(email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
  return from(this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)).pipe(
    map(firebaseUser => {
      // on success
      return true;
    }),
    catchError(error => {
      // on error
      return throwError(false);      // <-- use `throwError` to emit an `error` notification
    })
  );
}
```

Now the errors will be caught in the `error` callback

```js
this.someService.tryToLogin(...).subscribe(
  res => console.log(res),           // <-- will print `true` on successful login
  error => console.log(error)        // <-- will print `false` on failed login
);
```

Comment: I got:  A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return a value.

Comment: @itay: I overlooked the return statement. The `from..` should be `return from...`. I've updated the answer. Please see if it works for you now.